# Key for Google map

Tags: dictionary, key

To learn how works Google map I decided to create asp web page. I found on internet sample codes for static map 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap and for dynamic map

http://maps.google.com/maps. First code submits image to web page that i create and second code generates script file to draw map. I get key for static map and it works. However this key does not work for dynamic map. So I need to get key for this application. But this is not clear because there are different applications with similar functionality.

There is other question as well. This site i design to learn code. But it may happens that I will use similar code at job in the future. It is not clear from description. There is key for business data. I want to understand. If some company wants to incorporate Google map into their web site, does it automatically mean that they need key for business data or business data means something else (like adding to map some addresses important for business)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Javascript API V3 is free to use for a certain limits. but after that you have to pay. This limit is same for everyone, individual user, organisation or anyone.

There is another kind of Maps service provided by Google (Google Maps For Work) which includes advance features for Google maps, which may be useful for Company and Organisation on need basis.

Check out this link for complete information about Google maps Usage [Google Map API Licensing](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)